# Correlate data in large XML document

Tags: java, sax

I have an XML structure that looks like this:

```
<root>
    <index>
        <item>item 1</item>
        <item>item 2</item>
        <!-- many more items -->
    <index>
    <data>
        <row>
            <!-- relates to item 1 -->
            <cell>1</cell>
            <cell>2</cell>
            <!-- many more cells -->
        </row>
        <row>
            <!-- relates to item 2 -->
            <cell>3</cell>
            <cell>4</cell>
            <!-- many more cells -->
        </row>
        <!-- as many rows as there are items in the index -->    
    </data>
</root>
```

I'm trying to create a parser that outputs (to a database) a structure like this:

```
item 1 : [1, 2, ...]
item 2 : [3, 4, ...]
...
```

Normally, I'd use a sax parser, construct a HashMap, fill the keys when the parser passes the index element and afterwards add the cell data.

However, the document may contain a lot of data so I'm afraid I will run into memory issues.

My question is: how do I parse the file with as little memory usage as possible?

One thing I thought about was to construct two SAX parsers, one that runs over the index and another that parses the data. The problem is I have no idea how I can suspend one parser, start the other, suspend the other, restart the first one and so on.

Is this possible or are there better ways to deal with this?

BTW: sadly, I have absolutely no control over the format of the XML.

Comment: imho parsing xml will not be most memory expensive operation in your case. I would have paid attention to the database operations and transaction support. Also may be it makes sense not to collect data in collections/maps (or collect minimum data) but flush it to database on-the-fly? If you use some ORM solution you should set eyes on ORM session management and flush activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SAX parser isn't going to need to keep a lot in memory other than the hash map.  I would SAX parse the index element to generate `List<Item>` and then for each item element I can remove the item from the list (assert that it is in there, remove it) and then add to `Map<Item,List<Cell>>`.

The memory that you are going to be needing is the total number of items and an entry for each cell.  I don't think you need to maintain much more context than that when parsing using SAX.

Comment: Jeff & svaor, you're both right. This is some premature optimization that I shouldn't worry about.